# Is there a way to turn off spell check in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I run into this problem.  I have a textarea which I only want to use spell check when it's in focus.

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>

$('#editor').focusin(function(){
    $(this).attr('spellcheck', true);
});

$('#editor').focusout(function(){
    $(this).attr('spellcheck', false);
});
```

In chrome, if a word is misspelled there is a red line under the word. Even if I turn off the spell checker, the red line still exists. How do I remove this marker?

Comment: Sounds like a question for SuperUser more than Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's a programming problem.  I need to do this in the code

Comment: Recreate a textarea with same text in it, but before putting it in DOM, make `spellcheck` false first.

Comment: Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=841283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it figured out

```
function bindEditorFocus() {
    var $editor = $('#editor');
    $editor.focusin(function(){
        $(this).attr('spellcheck', true);
        toggleSpellingcheck(); // loop through all words to add marker
    }); 
    
    $editorblur(function(){
        $editor.attr('spellcheck', false);
        $editor.unbind();    // I need to unbind all function to avoid a loop 
        toogleSpellingcheck(); // loop through all words to remove marker
        $editor.blur();     //get out of text area
        bindEditorFocus();  // rebind all functions 
    });
}


function toogleSpellingcheck(){ 
    //this will loop through all words
    var $editor = $('#editor'); 
    var text = $editor.val();       
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        $editor.caret({start:i,end:i});
    }
}
```

the toogleSpellingcheck method loop through all words, it can be optimized to loop through words instead of characters, but this would need the jquery caret plugin

it's a bit messy, but works, anyone got suggestions on improvements please let me know

Answer (score 4):

I used this question to get an answer to your question: [Force spell check on a textarea in WebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884829/force-spell-check-on-a-textarea-in-webkit)

HTML:

```
<textarea id="editor" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#editor').focusin(function(){
    $(this).attr('spellcheck', true);
});

$('#editor').focusout(function() {
    $(this).attr('spellcheck', false);
    forceSpellcheck($(this));
});

    var canCheck = true;
    function forceSpellcheck($textarea) {
  if (canCheck) {
    canCheck = false;

    $textarea.focus();
    $textarea.attr('spellcheck', false);
    var characterCount = $textarea.val().length;

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    for (var i = 0; i < characterCount; i++ ) {
      selection.modify("move", "backward", "character");
    }

    // Remove focus from the element, since the word under
    // the cursor won't have a misspelling marker.
    $textarea.blur();
  } else {
    canCheck = true;
  }
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QgsRU/13/

Comment: That loop with constant 1000 doesn't look so good. you can get the amount of words with `.split(\s)`. Fix that and you got my upvote.

Comment: Truth be told I didn't studied that method. I just copy pasted it. I'l l look into that. Thanks gdoron!

Comment: It does not even work at all. It hang my browser, and I can't blur it.

Comment: Really? I have no problem with it.

Comment: Yep, you are right guys, I found the problem. Too many blurs :P

Comment: the text.blur() and $('#editor').focusout(function() call forceSpellcheck causes a dead loop, but i got your idea there, move cursor across all words to turn spellcheck marker off right?, let me check if it works

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it. I fixed a little bit. It can still needs more work. I'm not 100% happy with the flag solution.

Comment: This works in Firefox 76 but doesn't appear to work in Chrome 80.

Answer (score 0):

While specifying *spellcheck="false"* in the < textarea > tag will certainly disable that feature, it's handy to be able to toggle that functionality on and off as needed after the page has loaded. So here's a non-jQuery way to set the *spellcheck* attribute programmatically:

:

```
<textarea id="my-ta" spellcheck="whatever">abcd dcba</textarea>
```

:

```
function setSpellCheck( mode ) {
    var myTextArea = document.getElementById( "my-ta" )
        , myTextAreaValue = myTextArea.value
    ;
    myTextArea.value = '';
    myTextArea.setAttribute( "spellcheck", String( mode ) );
    myTextArea.value = myTextAreaValue;
    myTextArea.focus();
}
```

:

```
setSpellCheck( true );
setSpellCheck( 'false' );
```

The function argument may be either boolean or string.

No need to loop through the textarea contents, we just cut 'n paste what's there, and then set focus.

Tested in *blink* engines (Chrome(ium), Edge, etc.)