# How do i force spellchecker to invoke on click of any text area in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, spell-checking

Is there any way in which spellchecker can be enforced to work on statement without using any external plugins. I have a scenario in which control of type text gets generated on fly.Hence even though spellchecker attribute has been applied to it. wrong spelling does not gets highlighted when i focus back to that control.Surprisingly spellchecker works in Firefox and Chrome even though i focus out.Issue seems to be in IE.Also not complete sentence gets grammar checked if i focus out and get back as control is created on fly. I was looking around the way in which I can forcefully make spellchecker to work on text areas and then hook it into javascript event.

Comment: What spell checker are you talking about? If you mean the default spell checker of the browser, I don't think there's a way to influence it as it's controlled by the user. If you mean something else, please add more information to your question and try to be more clear.

Comment: Yes I am talking about browsers spellchecker.I want to understand how it internally works. It spell checks only once i start typing, so scenario in which already incorrect words has been entered and saved does not highlight the incorrect words until i focus back and start typing new word. So I was thinking is there a way to force browsers spell checker to run when I focus in that control? Hope I am making sense.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5221809/682583

Comment: Try exploring simulating a click event when page loads. Or, try a JS spellchecking library which you'll have full control over.