# Alternative to forceSpellCheck on contenteditable elements in Webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit, contenteditable

I'm trying to force spell check on a contenteditable element that is not being directly modified by the user's keystrokes (i.e. I'm translating events and performing content changes, selections, etc, via Javascript). This is an issue, as Webkit browsers only attempt to spell check content that is from the user, of which I have none via the event translations.

Element.forceSpellCheck() remains unsupported everywhere which should be the right way to do this.

The technique for dealing with this on inputs was to mimic a selection on each word as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884829/force-spell-check-on-a-textarea-in-webkit).

I haven't had any luck in getting this technique working on contenteditable elements. The only behavior that will reliably result in the spellchecker's red underline is using the arrow keys and not overriding the events - only when the cursor is placed directly on a misspelled word will the visual red line appear.

Is there another strategy to try out for dealing with this?